# Why can't I receive messages from mosquitto broker for a particular user in the ACL file?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm having trouble figuring out why I can subscribe to all topics with one user but not the other. I set them up at different points in time, maybe I forgot a step from the original user.

Mosquitto broker v1.5.5

acl_file contains

```
user foo
topic readwrite #

user bar
topic readwrite #
```

When I connect with user **foo** and subscribe to `'#'`, I get all messages from my publish test.

When I connect with user **bar** and subscribe to `'#'`, I get no messages from my publish test.

When I try to connect with a bad username/password for user **bar** I get an expected error. Mosquitto's log clearly shows bar connecting successfully.

When user **foo** is connected and a message is published, the mosquitto log shows `Received PUBLISH` then `Sending PUBACK` then `Sending PUBLISH`

When user **bar** is connected and a message is published, the mosquitto log shows `Received PUBLISH` then `Sending PUBACK` and does not show `Sending PUBLISH`

When I reverse the entries in my acl file to,

```
user bar
topic readwrite #

user foo
topic readwrite #
```

neither user gets the `Sending PUBLISH` message. I'm hoping someone else can spot the source of the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching the mosquitto changelog I got the idea that some whitespace might be to blame. I checked my acl file again and found a space that was the source of the problem:

For the offending user I had a space after the `#` wildcard in, `topic readwrite #`

Now user **foo** is receiving messages